# SQL Server Dynamic String Not Working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a string in an Audit table for any modifications made to the data. I've created this update trigger and everything is working just fine, except that my strings were broken into different entries based on the columes that are updated. Like this:

> 8 Employee with ID = 1 changed DepartmentID from 1 to 4
>
> 9   Employee with ID = 1 changed FIRSTNAME from Sam to Matt

Instead, I need all the updates to be rolled up in one long string. Like this:

> 8 Employee with ID = 1 changed DepartmentID from 1 to 4 FIRSTNAME from Sam to Matt

Can anyone figure out what the problem is for my code?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_tblEmployee_ForUpdate]
ON [dbo].[tblEmployee]
FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID INT
    DECLARE @OldFName NVARCHAR(20), @NewFName NVARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @OldLName NVARCHAR(20), @NewLName NVARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @OldDOB DATETIME, @NewDOB DATETIME
    DECLARE @OldCity NVARCHAR (20), @NewCity NVARCHAR (20)
    DECLARE @OldSalary INT, @NewSalary INT
    DECLARE @OldGender NVARCHAR(20), @NewGender NVARCHAR(20)
    DECLARE @OldDeptID INT, @NewDeptID INT

    DECLARE @AuditString NVARCHAR(1000)

    SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM inserted

    WHILE (EXISTS(SELECT ID FROM #TempTable))
    BEGIN
        SET @AuditString =''

        SELECT TOP 1 @ID = ID, @NewFName = First_Name, @NewLName = Last_Name, 
        @NewDOB = DateOfBirth, @NewCity = City, @NewSalary = Salary,
        @NewGender = Gender, @NewDeptID = DepartmentID
        FROM #TempTable

        SELECT @OldFName = First_Name, @OldLName = Last_Name, 
        @OldDOB = DateOfBirth, @OldCity = City, @OldSalary = Salary,
        @OldGender = Gender, @OldDeptID = DepartmentID
        FROM deleted WHERE ID = @ID

        SET @AuditString = 'Employee with ID = ' + CAST(@ID AS NVARCHAR (4)) + ' changed'
        IF(@OldFName <> @NewFName)
            SET @AuditString = @AuditString + ' FIRSTNAME from ' + @OldFName + ' to ' + @NewFName

        IF(@OldLName <> @NewLName)
            SET @AuditString = @AuditString + ' LASTNAME from ' + @OldLName + ' to ' + @NewLName

        IF(@OldDOB <> @NewDOB)
            SET @AuditString = @AuditString + ' DOB from ' + CAST(@OldDOB AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ' to ' + CAST(@NewDOB AS NVARCHAR(100))

        IF(@OldCity <> @NewCity)
            SET @AuditString = @AuditString + ' CITY from ' + @OldCity + ' to ' + @NewCity

        IF(@OldSalary <> @NewSalary)
            SET @AuditString = @AuditString + ' SALARY from ' + @OldSalary + ' to ' + @NewSalary

        IF(@OldGender <> @NewGender)
            SET @AuditString = @AuditString + ' GENDER from ' + @OldGender + ' to ' + @NewGender

        IF(@OldDeptID <> @NewDeptID)
            SET @AuditString = @AuditString + ' DepartmentID from ' + CAST(@OldDeptID AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ' to ' + CAST(@NewDeptID AS NVARCHAR(5))

        INSERT INTO tblAudit VALUES (@AuditString)

        DELETE FROM #TempTable WHERE ID = @ID
    END
END
```

Comment: What is the problem here? `9 Employee with ID = 1` is a different employee than `8 Employee with ID = 7`, based on your loop you want to update one employee changes at a time, is this not so?

Comment: What if you have multiple rows updated with multiple columns having been changed for each row; would you want just one row in your audit table? Or one row for each row having been updated?

Comment: @larsts Each auditing statement will only contain any updates to one row of data. When multiple rows are updated, there should be multiple auditing statements for each row.

Comment: Your trigger has a major flaw in it as it assumes (wrongly) to be fired per updated row, while in reality it will be fired per update statement. This means that if you ever run an update statement that targets multiple rows, your trigger will fail and you'll get an error message `subquery returned more then 1 value...`

Comment: @ZoharPeled Assuming the ID's are unique, what statement would trigger the more than 1 value error?

Comment: `UPDATE tblEmployee SET .... WHERE ID IN(1, 2, 3)` is one example...

Comment: I meant what part of the trigger. As far as I can see the trigger implements a pseudo-cursor where each row from inserted is handled at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must admit I can't see why your trigger would insert one row for each column changed.

However I would regardless try to rewrite the trigger using a set based approach in stead of the row-by-row you have implemented.

Something like:

```
INSERT INTO tblAudit
SELECT 'Employee with ID = ' + CAST(@ID AS NVARCHAR (4)) + ' changed '
        + CASE WHEN deleted.First_Name == deleted.First_Name THEN '' ELSE ' DOB from ' + CAST(deleted.DOB AS NVARCHAR(100)) + ' to ' + CAST(inserted.DOB AS NVARCHAR(100)) END
        + CASE WHEN deleted.City == inserted.City THEN '' ELSE ' CITY from ' + deleted.City + ' to ' + inserted.City END 
        + CASE WHEN deleted.Salary == inserted.Salary THEN '' ELSE ' SALARY from ' + deleted.Salary + ' to ' + inserted.Salary END
        + CASE WHEN deleted.Gender == inserted.Gender THEN '' ELSE ' GENDER from ' + deleted.Gender + ' to ' + inserted.Gender END
        + CASE WHEN deleted.DeptID == inserted.DeptID THEN '' ELSE ' DepartmentID from ' + CAST(deleted.DeptID AS NVARCHAR(5)) + ' to ' + CAST(inserted.DeptID AS NVARCHAR(5)) END
FROM Inserted LEFT JOIN Deleted ON Inserted.Id = Deleted.Id
```

Comment: If the columns are nullable you would need to add some handling making sure the equality checks are ok and also making sure that you don't conatenate NULL to the string resulting in a NULL value being inserted in the audit table.